# Structures in C

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to make a seat reservation program using structures and functions (as part of my effort to try to learn C). 
In the following code I have some problems in:

-Lines 82,143 ( seat reservation check is not working consistently) (Solved)
I changed  from temp to temp - 1  the code in these lines and everything is normal..

-Lines 109 and 122 where I want to compare two phone-numbers that are saved as unsigned short arrays of 10 elements. (Solved)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int i,j,numberofseats,temp;
char selection;
typedef struct
    {
    char fullname[40];
    unsigned short phonenr[10];
    unsigned int seatnr;
    }PASSENGERS;

void changeData(PASSENGERS *target){
    char firstname[20];
    char lastname[20];
    char phone[11];
    printf("Enter passenger's first name:");
    scanf("%s",firstname);
    printf("Enter passenger's last name:");
    scanf("%s",lastname);
    strcpy(target->fullname,firstname);
    strcat (target->fullname, " ");
    strcat(target->fullname,lastname);
    printf("Enter passenger's phone Nr:");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++) scanf("%hu",&(target->phonenr[i]));
    }

void cancelSeat(PASSENGERS *target){
    strcpy(target->fullname,"\0");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
    target->phonenr[i]=0;
    printf("Seat Nr %d is now free",temp);

    }


int main(void)
{
numberofseats=53;


PASSENGERS passenger[numberofseats];
for (j=0;j<numberofseats;j++)
    {passenger[j].seatnr=j+1;
    strcpy(passenger[j].fullname,"\0");
    }



    do{
    printf("\n\nNeo Sistima katagrafis thesewn leoforeiou\n");
    printf("Please make a selection:\n\n");
    printf("0. Exit\n");
    printf("1. Empty Seats \n");
    printf("2. Book Specific Seat \n");
    printf("3. Advanced Search of booked Seats\n");
    printf("4. Cancel Seat Booking\n");
    printf("5. Show List of booked Seats\n");
    scanf(" %c",&selection);

    if (selection=='1')
        {int freeseats = 0;
        for (j=0; j<numberofseats; j++)
            {
            strcmp(passenger[j].fullname,"\0")==0 ? freeseats = freeseats + 1 : freeseats ;}
            printf ("There are %d free seats in this bus \n", freeseats);
            printf("Seats that are available are:\n");

        for (j=0; j<numberofseats; j++)
            {if (strcmp(passenger[j].fullname,"\0")==0)
                printf ("%hd\n", passenger[j].seatnr);
            }
        freeseats = 0;
        }

    else if (selection=='2')
        {
        printf("Please give seat nr (between 1 and %d) that you want to book:\n", numberofseats);
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        if (temp >numberofseats || temp <= 0)
            {printf("Error: Seat nr should be between 1 and %d", numberofseats);}
         else if (strcmp(passenger[temp].fullname,"\0")!=0)
            printf("Error: Seat is already booked");

        else
        changeData(&passenger[temp-1]);

        }

 else if (selection=='3')
        {
        char tempsel,tmpfirst[20],tmplast[20];
        unsigned short tempphone[10];
        int counter, checkphone;
        unsigned int tempseat;
        printf("Do you want to search with Name (1) or Phone Nr (2)?\n");
        scanf(" %c",&tempsel);

        if (tempsel == '1')
        {   printf("Enter passenger's first name:");
            scanf("%s",tmpfirst);
            printf("Enter passenger's last name:");
            scanf("%s",tmplast);
            strcat (tmpfirst, " ");
            strcat(tmpfirst,tmplast);
            for (j=0;j<numberofseats;j++)
            if (strcmp(passenger[j].fullname,tmpfirst)==0)
                printf ("Passenger %s has seat nr #: %hd\n",tmpfirst,passenger[j].seatnr);
        }
        else if (tempsel == '2')
        {   checkphone=0;
            printf("Enter passenger's phonenr:");
            for (i=0;i<10;i++)
            scanf("%hu",&tempphone[i]);
            for (j=0;j<numberofseats;j++)
                {
                counter=0;
                for(i=0;i<10;i++)
                    {
                if (passenger[j].phonenr[i]==tempphone[i])
                    counter=counter+1;
                    if (counter ==10)
                    {checkphone=1;
                    tempseat=passenger[j].seatnr;
                    }}
                }
                if (checkphone==1)
                {printf ("Passenger has seat #: %hd\n",tempseat);
                checkphone=0;}

        }
        }



    else if (selection=='4')
        {
        printf("Please give seat nr (between 1 and %d) that you want to cancel booking:\n", numberofseats);
        scanf("%d",&temp);
        if (temp >numberofseats || temp <= 0)
            {printf("Error: Seat nr should be between 1 and %d", numberofseats);}
         else if (strcmp(passenger[temp].fullname,"\0")==0)
            printf("Error: Seat is already free");

        else
        cancelSeat(&passenger[temp-1]);

        }




    } while (selection!='0');









}
```

Comment: Always take your compiler's warning serious. Fix the code until no more warnings are issued. Do not use casts to do so.

Answer (score 1):

you have two problems :-

1. passed integer in strcpy and strcmp.
2. to print integer data you used %s (for temp)

Do modify your code like that :-

```
void cancelSeat(PASSENGERS *target){
    strcpy(target->fullname,"\0");
    for (i=0;i<10;i++)
//    strcpy(target->phonenr[i],"\0");
    printf("Seat Nr %d is now free",temp);

    }
```

and change you case where you comparing telephone number

```
   if (strcmp(passenger[j].phonenr[i],tempphone[i])==0) ==> if (passenger[j].phonenr[i]==tempphone[i])
```

Comment: Thank you! in place of the phone comparison, I changed a little bit more the code and now it seems to work..

Comment: @baskon1 great.

Comment: @baskon1 as you are new to c, so before writing a code, draw all logic on notebook first. You will identify easily what you are doing and yes try to understand what complier compliant. Use man page for API syntax.